# Using Javascript to open an .xls file from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Cannot find anywhere how to make a drop-down list open a `.xls` file.

What my code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function download(d) {
 if (d !== '') {
  window.open('URL goes here/' + d);
 }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
Excel List:
 <select name="download" onchange="download(this.value)" style="width:150px;" >
     <option value="">Select an Excel list</option>
        <option value="file_name1.xls">File name</option>
        <option value="file_name2.xls">File name</option>
    </select>


</body>
</html>
```

When I do this, it opens 4 additional tabs and then asked if I want to open or save the excel file. How can I make it work by choosing the excel list and not having the 4 additional tabs open and only show to open or save the file?

Comment: You can't force a file download from JS. JS doens't hav access to the headers. You'd need some PHP.

Comment: This exact code work perfect for PDF files

Comment: Read up on how a browser works. You cannot FORCE a PDF download from JS. The browser will try to display it if it has a PDF plugin, otherwise it will be downloaded. don't assume that just because it works in your browser that it will always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use '_self'.

window.open('URL goes here/' + d, '_self');

OR

window.location.href = 'URL goes here/' + d;

Answer (score 0):

The key to your question is the `window.open()` method.  It is documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).  What this method does is open a new window using the first parameter as the name of the URL to load in the new window.  The `window.open()` method can take a value as parameter two that determines where the new browser window should be loaded.  The default is `_blank` which opens a new window (tab) which is what you are seeing.  It sounds like you may want to supply `_self` to replace the current page with the selected file.

Your new code would then become:

```
function download(d) {
    if (d !== '') {
        window.open('URL goes here/' + d, '_self');
    }
}
```